# JS if statement not working with else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

so i started making a game and i am trying to make an item to buy and i have a function but for some reason it skips over the code when everything that i want even though it shouldn't

```
function buyConsole(){
  if(money >= 400 && console === 1){
    console += 1
    money -= 400
  }else{
    if(console == 1){
      alert("you already have a console")
    }else{
      alert("not enought money and/or error A0000: function call error")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `money`? What is `console`?

Comment: We need more info. The variable for money and console and much more details about your issue to be able to help..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explicitly describe the desired behaviour and the actual behaviour. Which part is skipped? (Also, be careful about having a global variable called `console`, because there is already a global `console` object with methods used for debugging.)

Comment: You have `console === 1`, but I think that should be `0`? You seem to be using `console` as a boolean flag. Also, in the second `if`, you use `==` rather than `===` as in the first `if`.

Comment: the console === 1 thing worked thanks

Comment: How do you call the function? Where does those variables get defined?

Comment: If `console == 1` doesn't work, then `console === 1` won't (unless there is a serious problem elsewhere; of course the code is not a complete example / test case so..).

Comment: `console` is a bad variable name. EG console.log...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(money >= 400 && console === 1){
```

to this :

```
if(money >= 400 && console ==0){
console += 1 money -= 400
}else{ 
if(console >= 1)
{ alert("you already have a console") }
else{
alert("not enought money and/or error A0000: function call error") }
}
```

because you can still buy a console even though you already have one unless you want to restrict the user to just purchasing a maximum of one console?